# How to play the audio files directly from res/raw folder?

Tags: android, media-player, r.java-file

I have multiple audio files in `res/raw` folder. I showing `ListView` that contains audio files name. I want to play the corresponding audio file when user select into the `ListView`. I have used `setDataSource(path)`, but it showing error while playing. How play the audio files directly from that folder? Or Is there any other way?

Comment: i need a small info, how many audio files you have kept in res folder and what's the total size of those mp3 files. thanks:)

Comment: You need to add more information to this question. What file types you are trying to play and what the error/stack trace message is you are receiving.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

add this code in onItemClickListener.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long id) {                 
                TextView txtView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_view);
                String fname=txtView.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

                                int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(fname, "raw", getPackageName());

                              MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID);
                    mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I got the `ResourceNotFound` exception while using like this. I have used `getResources().getIdentifier(audioname, "res/raw", getPackageName());`.

Comment: don't use res/raw. use like this getResources().getIdentifier(audioname, "raw", getPackageName());

Comment: Still same problem and exception

Comment: can you show how you are displaying text in listview. eg. if raw folder contains file like sound.mp3 then you should display the file name as 'sound' only, don't display file extension.

Comment: now i edited the answer in this line String fname=txtView.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

Comment: Perfect. :) I passed that mp3 extension also. this is the problem.

Comment: What is txt_view in R.id.txt_view? I am getting a type error whenever I try this.

Answer (score 34):

**try this for playing from raw ::**

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer2;
mPlayer2= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bg_music_wav);
        mPlayer2.start();
```

**permission in manifest file ::**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

## Update::

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long id) {     
  MediaPlayer mPlayer2;
if(position==1)
{
    mPlayer2= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song1);
            mPlayer2.start();
}else it() .....
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I can play by using `MediaPlayer.create(...)`. This is not a problem. My problem is i want to play particular audio file when select from `ListView`. Because Lot of files available on `res\raw` folder.

Comment: as i mention in code "bg_music_wav.wav" you can play any file

Comment: one more thing you need to put code in click listener and apply your own logic

Comment: For example, I have 1.mp3,2.mp3 up to 100.mp3. Now user select 49.mp3 in `ListView`. How to play that particular file?

Comment: why you not try to load file in server and ply from it?

Comment: This is off mode application.

Comment: becase it is easy in your case to hadle 100 file because it is boring

Comment: what do you mean off mode application.? elaborate please.

Comment: Here I mention off mode means without internet connection.

Comment: No need to add any permission

Answer (score 6):

```
mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.Video_FrontPage);
uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.urPackageName/" + R.raw.welcom_video);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.start();
```

Comment: I am unable to access R.raw.filename. I have made a raw folder in my res folder and have also put my file in it.

Answer (score 4):

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {

          // selected item 
          String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

          int [] resID= {R.raw.sound1,R.raw.sound2,R.raw.sound3};
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID[position]);

          mediaPlayer.start();
          // sending data to new activity


      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1)
mediaPlayer.start() // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you
```

Answer (score 1):

Place your audio file in the res/raw folder and call it from the create method of MediaPlayer.

`MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_file_name).start();`

Eg:

```
MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

To play audio from the raw folder call this method. In my case my file name was **notificaion.mp3**:

```
AudioPlayer().playAudio(mContext, "notificaion")
```

Here is the AudioPlayer class:

```
class AudioPlayer {
private var mMediaPlayer: MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()

private fun stopAudio() {
   try {
       mMediaPlayer.release()
   }catch (ex: Exception){
       ex.printStackTrace()
   }

}

fun playAudio(mContext: Context, fileName: String) {
    try {
        stopAudio()
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, mContext.resources.getIdentifier(fileName, "raw", mContext.packageName))
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener {  stopAudio() }
        mMediaPlayer.start()
    }catch (ex: Exception){
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long id) {                 
                TextView txtView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_view);
                String fname=txtView.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

                                int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(fname, "raw", getPackageName());

                              MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID);
                    mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
```

add this code in onItemClickListener and one more information is you can't play any file other than mp3 and the mp3 file must be the original extension as file.