# Function argument as filename

Tags: android

Addig a file to MediaPlayer is easy:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(Myctivity.this, R.raw.sound);
```

But what if I have the filename as an argument coming from a function like this?

```
  public void CreateSound(String filename, float volume)
    {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Myctivity.this, R.raw.???);
             mp.setVolume(volume, volume);
           try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           mp.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7499605/645270) thread mentions

```
 int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(fname, "raw", getPackageName());
```

which takes a file name and fetches the ID. (**OBS:** Before using the file name it's converted to lower case)
This can then be passed to the MediaPlayer:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID);
```

Comment: Thanks! I remember having seen this somewhere, I just forget it