# How to set Sound RingtoneManager from R.raw

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

How to set Sound RingtoneManager from R.raw....

I want to set my sound but I have no idea to set it

```
Uri defaultRingtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, defaultRingtoneUri);
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
                {
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

thanks for you help! and sorry my english is not good

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499605/how-to-play-the-audio-files-directly-from-res-raw-folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(fileName, "raw", getPackageName());
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

I hope it helps you. Make sure fileName is in lowercase.

Note that fileName doesnot contain any extensions. Don't write any extension just the name of file.
For Example for ringtone.mp3 - write:

```
.getIndentifier("ringtone","raw",getPackageName());
```

You can even input it via `InputStream`.

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(getResources().getIdentifier("fileName","raw", getPackageName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean ho to load raw resource to MediaPlayer try this:

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.example);
```